# How to test that I have unsubscribed using ngx-auto-unsubscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, subscription, unsubscribe

Is there a way in which I can write a unit test to check whether I have unsubscribed successfully from my `Observable` subscription?

I am using [`ngx-auto-unsubscribe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-auto-unsubscribe).

**example:**

```
@AutoUnsubscribe()
@Component
// Template and style urls

export class MyComp implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   mySub: Subscription;

   constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.myService.doSomething.subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res);
      })
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     // Only used for AOT (ahead of time) compilation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's a way (even though I don't think it's necessary to test that).

I'm not going to write the whole test for you but here's the logic:

- Create a parent component (let's call it `MockComponent`) in your test with a basic `ngIf` condition to display your `MyComp` or not
- Mock the observable from your service using another observable that you built like that:

.

```
const obsCleanUpFunction = jasmine.createSpy();

const obs$ = new Observable(observer => {
  //following will be called when/if the observable if completed
  return obsCleanUpFunction;
});
```

- Create the component `MockComponent` with the `MyComp` in it
- Run a change detection to pass within the `ngOnInit` and subscribe to it
- On the component `MockComponent`, set the condition to display `MyComp` to false --> it'll be destroyed by the `ngIf` evaluating to false
- Expect the jasmine spy `toHaveBeenCalled`

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. It doesn't seem very worth it :-P